# Exclude from result if Sum = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to exclude records from the result if `(+)LotQty` has the same with `(-)LotQty` but different `Transtype`.

Example : from this

```
Docentry  Transtype  LotQty
4594      67          250.000000
4643      60         -250.000000
9253      67          100.000000
16822     60         -200.000000
```

to this

```
Docentry  Transtype  LotQty
9253      67         100.000000
16822     60        -200.000000**
```

Comment: couldn't you simplify the sample data and expected output!!?

Comment: so confusing, what is the relationship of docentry 4594 and 4643? why the other two didn't get subtracted with each other?

Comment: @Ceeee , Actually may Column pa yan na ItemCode , dun sila parehas kaya automatic na subtracted na sya . gusto ko sanang i disregard ung ganoon case . Salamat sir kung masasagot mo :)

Comment: I see, you are a filipino :) checkout my answer and hope it helps even a little

Comment: and try to speak in english even if you know someone is same with your native language

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure on the Group by part because of the aggregate but, you can try this:

```
 SELECT A.Docentry, A.Transtype, A.LotQty 
 FROM your_table as A 
 WHERE A.ItemCode IN 
    (SELECT B.ItemCode 
      FROM your_table as B 
      WHERE SUM(B.LotQty) = 0 
      GROUP BY B.ItemCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ABS function to get the absolute value and compare that.

```
Select * from Table T1 join Table T2 Where ABS(T1.LotQty)<>ABS(T2.LotQty)
```